# Replacing the values from another data from based on the information in the first column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to merge informations in two different data frames, but problem begins with uneven dimensions and trying to use not the column index but the information in the column. merge function in R or join's (dplyr) don't work with my data.

I have to dataframes (One is subset of the others with updated info in the last column):

`df1=data.frame(Name = print(LETTERS[1:9]), val = seq(1:3), Case = c("NA","1","NA","NA","1","NA","1","NA","NA"))`

```
  Name val Case
1  A   1   NA
2  B   2    1
3  C   3   NA
4  D   1   NA
5  E   2    1
6  F   3   NA
7  G   1    1
8  H   2   NA
9  I   3   NA
```

Some rows in the `Case` column in `df1` have to be changed with the info in the `df2` below:

`df2 = data.frame(Name = c("A","D","H"), val = seq(1:3), Case = "1")`

```
    Name val Case
1    A   1    1
2    D   2    1
3    H   3    1
```

So there's nothing important in the `val` column, however I added it into the examples since I want to indicate that I have more columns than two and also my real data is way bigger than the examples.

Basically, I want to change specific rows by checking the information in the first columns (in this case, they're unique letters) and in the end I still want to have `df1` as a final data frame.

for a better explanation, I want to see something like this:

```
  Name val Case
1  A   1    1
2  B   2    1
3  C   3   NA
4  D   1    1
5  E   2    1
6  F   3   NA
7  G   1    1
8  H   2    1
9  I   3   NA
```

Note changed information for `A`,`D` and `H`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%in%` from base-r is there to rescue.

```
    df1=data.frame(Name = print(LETTERS[1:9]), val = seq(1:3), Case = c("NA","1","NA","NA","1","NA","1","NA","NA"), stringsAsFactors = F)

    df2 = data.frame(Name = c("A","D","H"), val = seq(1:3), Case = "1", stringsAsFactors = F)




    df1$Case <- ifelse(df1$Name %in% df2$Name, df2$Case[df2$Name %in% df1$Name], df1$Case)

df1

Output:

> df1
  Name val Case
1    A   1    1
2    B   2    1
3    C   3   NA
4    D   1    1
5    E   2    1
6    F   3   NA
7    G   1    1
8    H   2    1
9    I   3   NA
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked great and really fast even with a huge dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do using `dplyr`:

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("Name")) %>% 
  mutate(val = if_else(is.na(val.y), val.x, val.y), 
         Case = if_else(is.na(Case.y), Case.x, Case.y)) %>% 
 select(Name, val, Case)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution. However, in your code there's a NA dependency but actually I would be great if you can suggest something more universal, something can be doable for all kind of values.